# If I call a function in the head section of JavaScript for-of loop, is it guarantied to be called only once?

Tags: javascript, for-of-loop

I have tried the code below in Firefox and Chrome:

```js
function test() {
    console.log("***")
    return [1,2,3]
}

for (const t of test()) {
    console.log(t)
}
```

The `test` function was called only once. Is it the standard behavior for this kind of loop? Is it like the initialization part of `for ([initialization]; [condition]; [final-expression])` loop? I didn't find the explanation on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) and I didn't understand much from [ECMA standard](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#sec-runtime-semantics-forinofheadevaluation).

Comment: Yep, that's how it works. The part after `of` is only evaluated once (luckily).

Comment: The spec is about as clear as the spec gets; the expression to the right of `of` is evaluated once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ECMAScript specification splits the [runtime semantics of the `for..in` and `for..of` construct](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-language-statements-and-declarations.html#sec-runtime-semantics-forinofloopevaluation) into two parts:

> *ForInOfStatement* : `for` `(` *LeftHandSideExpression* `of` AssignmentExpression `)` *Statement*
>
> 1. Let *keyResult* be ? ForIn/OfHeadEvaluation(« », *AssignmentExpression*, iterate).
> 2. Return ? ForIn/OfBodyEvaluation(*LeftHandSideExpression*, *Statement*, *keyResult*, iterate, assignment, *labelSet*).

So we first have the "head" evaluation (involving the "AssignmentExpression" at the right of `of`), and after that, the "body" evaluation, which uses the *keyResult* (not the *AssignmentExpression*).

The ["head" evaluation](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-language-statements-and-declarations.html#sec-runtime-semantics-forinofheadevaluation) involves the actual evaluation in step 3 of that procedure:

> 3. Let *exprRef* be the result of evaluating *expr*.

The ["body" evaluation](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-language-statements-and-declarations.html#sec-runtime-semantics-forin-div-ofbodyevaluation-lhs-stmt-iterator-lhskind-labelset) involves the actual iteration in step 6:

> 6. Repeat